# Disable proxy configuration on android

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, vpn, proxy

I recently use VPN client on my Android 5.1.1 after network was censored in my country. Later, after uninstalling, I can remark that when connecting to wifi, my phone is still configuring proxy, and I cannot connect to internet correctly. 
Is there a solution ? What do I need to do ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix this, I finally reset my phone.